# Using code : text in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm just programming an application with a lot of texts So just want to use text control in VB.net
But When I use label1.text= " my text .... " that has 6 lines it shows me error !!!

For Example this is my text :

Oxygen is a chemical element with symbol O and atomic number 8. It is a member of the chalcogen group on the periodic table and is a highly reactive nonmetallic element and oxidizing agent that readily forms compounds (notably oxides) with most elements.[1] By mass, oxygen is the third-most abundant element in the universe, after hydrogen and helium.[2] At STP, two atoms of the element bind to form dioxygen, a diatomic gas that is colorless, odorless, and tasteless, with the formula O
 2.

Many major classes of organic molecules in living organisms, such as proteins, nucleic acids, carbohydrates, and fats, contain oxygen, as do the major inorganic compounds that are constituents of animal shells, teeth, and bone. Most of the mass of living organisms is oxygen as it is a part of water, the major constituent of lifeforms (for example, about two-thirds of human body mass). Elemental oxygen is produced by cyanobacteria, algae and plants, and is used in cellular respiration for all complex life. Oxygen is toxic to obligately anaerobic organisms, which were the dominant form of early life on Earth until O
 2 began to accumulate in the atmosphere. Free elemental O
 2 only began to accumulate in the atmosphere about 2.5 billion years ago during the Great Oxygenation Event, about a billion years after the first appearance of these organisms.[3][4] Diatomic oxygen gas constitutes 20.8% of the volume of air.[5] Oxygen is the most abundant element by mass in the Earth's crust as part of oxide compounds such as silicon dioxide, making up almost half of the crust's mass.[6]

And I want to show this text by code ::: 
Label1.text= " above text " But because it's multiline text after first line it shows error of code

What can I do?

Is there a way to use this code to show above text???

Comment: Could you show us your code, and what error messages you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot split a line of quoted text with a carriage return in VB.
Instead, you can do this:

```
label1.text = "this is the first line or paragraph" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
label1.text &= "this is the second (or third, fourth, etc.) line or paragraph" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
label1.text &= "this is the final line or paragraph"
```

Comment: Thanks but this is too long for kind of 15 lines

Comment: Split it by paragraph instead of by line.

Comment: but again too long and take much time and u must change the type of ur text to do it